# Vaadin Plugin for Grails installs but code completion does not work

Tags: grails, netbeans-7, vaadin7

I have tried to install the vaadin plugin for grails on both GGTS and Netbeans and even though it works, the IDE flags the vaadin imports as unable to resolve them and as a result code completion does not work for Vaadin components

It appears the plugin did not resolve its dependencies.

Also I notice the first time I run-app, while Vaadin plugin is installing, I get the following error:

```
|Installed plugin vaadin-7.1.9.1
......Error 
|
Error loading event script from file [target\work\plugins\vaadin-7.1.9.1\scripts\_Events.groovy] startup failed:
C:\ .....\target\work\plugins\vaadin-7.1.9.1\scripts\_Events.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.vaadin.grails.VaadinConfiguration
@ line 1, column 1.
import com.vaadin.grails.VaadinConfiguration
^
1 error
(Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Everything works after that but code completion and the unresolved error messages show up.

This happens even if I do a clean.

The version of grails used is 2.3.5 and netbeans is 7.4, GGTS is 3.4.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! me....

This did it for me:

Right click on project -> Grails Tools -> Resolve dependencies